# Extending the life of a temporary object by getting a reference to a subobject

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, temporary-objects

There is a subtle difference between the language used at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com) and by the [C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/) regarding when the life of a temporary object is extended (emphasis mine).

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary):

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to **a base subobject** of a temporary, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference,

From [The C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.temporary):

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of **a subobject** to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:

According to the standard, [a subject can be a member subject, a base class subject, or an array element](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.object#2).

If we go strictly by the verbiage of the standard in the following sample code

```
struct Foo 
{
   Foo() : a(10), b(20) {}
   ~Foo() { std::cout << "In Foo::~Foo()\n"; }
   int a;
   int b;
};

Foo getFoo()
{
   return Foo();
}

void testFoo1()
{
   int const& r = getFoo().a;
   std::cout << "In testFoo1()\n";
   (void)r; // Shut up the compiler
}
```

the life time of the object returned by `getFoo()` should extend for the lifetime of the reference. However, [a simple test](http://ideone.com/agtqZQ) seems to indicate that it does not.

Is the verbiage used by the standard a defect?
Is the compiler non-conformant?
Is the verbiage used by cppreference.com a defect?

**Update**

The language used at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) has been updated to (emphasis mine):

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to **a subobject** thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference, with the following exceptions:

Comment: A compiler doesn't do what the standard says. Must be a bug in the standard! Can't possibly be a bug in the compiler!

Comment: Snark aside, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54293. This is fixed in GCC 7. cppreference and the standard are correct as written.

Comment: @T.C., The verbiage use by cppreference.com implies, whether on purpose or not, the life of a temporary object is not extended by getting a reference to a member subobject.

Comment: Well, it didn't say it's not extended...fixed.

Comment: Work as expected with gcc/clang [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15c11035007512f8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the verbiage used by the standard a defect?

No.

> Is the compiler non-conformant?

Yes. As was pointed out in a comment, it has been fixed in a newer version of g++, g++ 7. Related link: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54293.

> Is the verbiage used by cppreference.com a defect?

Yes. The contents of [the page at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) has been updated.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that nobody has pointed out that it is a const reference and not a plain reference.  This makes a huge difference.  A non-const reference would not have the same effect.

Comment: @shargors, the `const&` part is implied. You cannot get a non-const reference to a temporary or a sub-object of the temporary.

Comment: That's correct. I would imagine that the standard would spell this out explicitly.